# Character disappears in exported PDF/PNG

Tags: octave

When I produce a simple graph in Octave, using the following lines of code:

```
data = [1:1:3,3,4,3:-1:1]
plot(data)
ylabel(strcat("Temperature [", char(0176), "C]"))
```

I get a nice plot:

[image: Plot in Octave]

However, when I export the plot as PDF or PNG, using the following code:

```
print("-dpdf", "-color", "output.pdf");
print("-dpng", "-color", "output.png");
```

I get a PDF and a PNG containing the same plot, but not the `°` char:

[image: PDF](PDF, zoomed Screenshot)

[image: PNG](PNG, zoomed Screenshot)

How can I make the character appear in the exported graphics?

Octave version: 4.2.0

Comment: Try with `ylabel('Temperature [^{o}C]')`

Comment: @SardarUsama: `ylabel('Temperature [^{o}C]')` could circumvent the problem and is definitely better than nothing, but the superscript `o` just looks like an o and not like a degrees symbol...

Comment: Have you tried with a a different graphics_toolkit ?

Comment: @matzeri: Yes, I have tried it with `graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")` as well. Almost the same result.